# Get all columns after GroupBy Operation Dask/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dask

I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
    id sim  col1    col2    year    extra
0   1   1    a       b      2021    H
1   2   2    a       b      2024    A
```

I want to groupby this df by ***col1 & col2*** and count the ***sim*** that comes in similar grouped columns. so i do this and i get this too..

```
ddf.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).agg({"sim":"list"}).compute()

                  
col1    col2     sim
a        b       [1, 2]
```

I also want to keep the row with highest year. So I did this too:

```
ddf.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).agg({"sim":"list", "year":"max"}).compute()
```

and got this df:

```
col1    col2    sim     year    
a         b    [1, 2]   2024
```

***Note: See the max year was 2024 between the grouped cols, so i kept that.***

But i lose other columns like id and extra. I also want to get those column based on maximum year value. So , wherever the year is maximum keep that row.

But i loose other columns like id, year and extra. So how can i get this.

Expected Result Df:

```
 id   col1  col2    sim     year    extra
  2    a      b    [1, 2]   2024      A
```

Comment: add `'year': 'last'` or `'year': 'max'` to the dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the values on `year` then `groupby` and aggregate using agg dict: `d` where `sim` is aggregated using list while the rest of the columns are aggregated using last

```
d = {**dict.fromkeys(ddf.columns, 'last'), 'sim': 'list'}
ddf.sort_values('year').groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result

```
   id     sim col1 col2  year extra
0   2  [2, 1]    a    b  2024     A
```

Comment: this works like charm but the sort_values("year") will result in 1 single partition. I need to scale out this on dask so that i wont get memory issue. Is there any idea i can do same thing on dask but with some parralelism.

Comment: @SudipAdhikari AFAIK the number of partitions returned by `sort_values`  will not always be 1 it depends on the dataset size..Although sorting do involve shuffles between the partition but I believe that should not be a problem here..

Comment: @SudipAdhikari by default Dask groupby-aggregations return a single partition, but you can change this with the `split_out` parameter (see https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html#Many-groups).

Comment: @scj13 but sorting needs to all shuffle. it will eventually take almose all ram. We can do on groupBy but what abt sorting???

Comment: How about changing the aggregation dictionary to `d = {**dict.fromkeys(ddf.columns, 'last'), 'sim': 'list', 'year': 'max'}`?